# Count no. of delimiters in line while ignoring the delimiter which is part of data value

Tags: python, delimiter, readline

I am reading one big csv file line by line and I want to count the no. of delimiters in each line.

But if the delimiter is part of data value, then it should not be counted.

**Few records of data set:**

```
com.abc.xyz, ple Sara, "DIT, Government of Maharashtra, India"
com.mtt.rder, News Maharashtra, Time Internet Limited"
com.grner.mahya, Mh Swth, "Public Health Department, Maharashtra"
```

In all 3 lines,  number of actual commas (which divides the data into multiple columns) are only 2

**but below code snippet outputs**

- 4 commas for line 1
- 2 for line 2
- 3 for line 3

**Code Snippet:**

```
file1 = open('file_name.csv', 'r') 

while True: 

    line = file1.readline() 
  
    if not line: 
        break
    
    print(line.count(','))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple way could be to use regex and remove everything between two `"`, so that the commas inside aren't counted.

```
import re
file1 = open('input.csv', 'r') 

while True: 
    line = file1.readline()   
    if not line: 
        break
    line = re.sub('".*?"', '', line)
    print(line.count(','))
```

Output:

```
2
2
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use csv package from python for counting cols:

```
import csv

with open('file_name.csv', 'rt') as f:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True)
    for line in csv_reader:
        print(len(line))
```

Comment: This one is giving 3 for each row, we would need 2 instead.

Comment: If you need exactly the number of commas, then you can subtract 1. I just think that the person is actually parsing the file and not counting the commas. By the way, this code works three times faster than through re ;)

Comment: I like the solution approach, this looks nice!

Comment: Substracting one may not be the right answer as the quoted part could have more than one comma.

Comment: Aparna Chaganti you don't understand at all what is going on in this code. It does not count commas, counts the number of csv file columns